# How to open a link and refer not to send?

Tags: php, curl, reference, get, referer

Hello friends i have a question, how to open a link from another site and not sending referer?

The site you tried to get the link from it, detects the header and do not let the link work.
The site you want to get links is http://fank.mobi/downloads/ngame/860/
I did a system by php curl to get the android games of this site. But the download links do not work. I do not want to save the files on my server, so I wanted to get the links.

I've tried opening the link using target _blank did not work.

I've tried to open the link in the header using php eg

```
header ("Referer: http://  site2.com");
header ("Location: http:// site2.com");
```

and did not work.

I've tried opening the link using javascript `document.location.href = "site2.com";`
and did not work

Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you have tagged the question with "curl", so have you tried a curl approach?

Comment: The client decides what to send as the referer, you can't control that from the server side.

Comment: "Did not work" isn't enough for us to work with..

Answer (score 2):

Have the source site use `https`.  Referer strings are not sent to an external site when the link was clicked on a secure page.

In Firefox, change the setting `network.http.sendRefererHeader` to 0.  You can set this by going to the URL `about:config` in Firefox.

Using cURL, omit the `Referer` header. If cURL didn't work, there was another reason; maybe you didn't send a valid user-agent or have a valid session cookie.

There is *no way* you can tell a browser not to send a Referer header using Javascript or PHP.  Short of having the user install a plugin to disable such functionality, I think the above methods are your only option.

Please clarify what you mean if these answers don't help.